# SVG clipPath coordinates issue

Tags: html, css, svg

I have some problem on SVG clipPath align and transform.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >
  <clipPath id="clipped">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"></circle>
  </clipPath>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></circle>
</svg>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:pink;
  clip-path: url(#clipped);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipped);
}
```

I have two circles inside of my svg with the same X and Y and R. As you can see my SVG element has width of 100% and height of 100% and the viewBox="0 0 600 600", so the contents of the svg will be transformed by resizing the browser window, except the clipped area of that div. In fact when I inspect elements with devTools, the position of both circles are the same, but masked area of that DIV is not in the right place. when I remove the viewBox, it will be ok, but I want my svg fits to screen. as I know the svg viewBox does not affect the clipPath, so what can I do to match the masked area in right place on top of the both circles even when I set the viewBox.
[Here is the CodePen](http://codepen.io/NavidNazarian/pen/WxGxde)

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for? The SVG has 100% x 100% of the body whereas the `div` has only 300px x 300px, so they will not match.

Comment: @Harry The pink area must match the stroked circle in codepen example. in fact it doesn't matter what is your div width or height. it will not affect on the result.

Comment: It will not match that's what I am saying and the reason is because your SVG is scaled whereas your `div` isn't.

Comment: I believe you are missing a "defs" to contain your clipPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an SVG clipPath on an HTML element, it is used as-is.  As it is defined.  It is not affected by any scaling that may be present in its parent SVG.

If you used the clipPath on an element in the SVG, it *would* be affected by the scaling.